# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity returning null with Machine Context type

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am working on an application that require last login time from the Windows machine. I'm using a `PrincipalContext` for that.

The code that I am using is working on few machines but in some machines the  `UserPrincipal` is begin returned as null:

```
private DateTime? GetLastLogin()
{
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName);
    UserPrincipal uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Environment.UserName);
    return uc.LastLogon;
}
```

The code is working fine on few machines but at the same time on some machines it is returning `UserPrincipal` as null. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName)
```

Says that you want to look up the account on the current machine. So you will only be able to find local accounts - accounts that exist only on the current machine.

If the user is logged in with an Active Directory account, then yes, your call to `FindByIdentity` will return nothing, because their account exists in Active Directory, not the local machine.

If you want a `UserPrincipal` object for the current user, you can just use [`UserPrincipal.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current):

```
private DateTime? GetLastLogin()
{
    return UserPrincipal.Current.LastLogon;
}
```

Just be careful how many times you do that. Each time you use `UserPrincipal.Current`, it creates a new `UserPrincipal` object, and the first time you use a new `UserPrincipal` object, it will go out and talk to AD, which takes time.

So it would be wise to keep a reference to the `UserPrincipal` object you get from `UserPrincipal.Current` and refer back to that same object every time you need to.